# I cant get 1920x1080 with Intel Linux Graphic Driver

Tags: drivers, xorg, intel-graphics, display-resolution

have a motherboard with integrated Intel HD 4600 Graphics.
Im running a fresh installed Ubuntu 15.10 with the official driver of Intel Installed: [intel linux 01 graphics](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0)

But i cant get resolutions higher than 1024x768 in the resolutions menu options.
With xrandr i can set a max resolution of 1280x720, but with 1920x1080 the resolution breaks.(Booting in windows i can set 1920x1080 and bigger resolutions).

this is my xorg.0.log. I think there are some mistakes, but I do not know how to resolve them:
http://pastebin.com/raw/pujD1hUw

I would greatly appreciate the help.
Regards!

Answer (score 8):

1. Temporary solution:

   - Open a terminal and type: `cvt 1920 1080 [your refresh rate]`

e.g. `cvt 1920 1080 60`

- output of the command likes this:

`Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync`

- copy the output line after the Modeline part and add it to xrandr:

  ```
  sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
  sudo xrandr --verbose --addmode VGA1 "1920x1080_60.00"
  sudo xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
  ```

If I see it right in your log you have 3 output: VGA1, HDMI1 and HDMI2. You can change the `--output VGA1` with the two HDMI if necessary.

2. Permanent solution:

   - Edit the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file with root privileges:

e.g. `sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

- Add/edit these parts:

  ```
  Section "Monitor"
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
  EndSection
  ```

and

```
    Section "Screen"
    SubSection "Display"
    Modes "1920x1080@60"
```

Restart the system.