# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't support wide screen 2560x1024

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics

From a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04, you don't have the support for the ultra-wide screen like LG 2560x1024.

My video-card is a AMD Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM] card.

Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't support installation of AMD drivers.

Comment: Regarding AMD: see http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04 You need to use the open-source AMDGPU or the open-source Radeon driver until AMD provides drivers. And the ultra-wide screen is supported but due to this you probably need to manually add it.

Comment: You can adapt this solution, but with 2560x1024 resolution: [Click](http://askubuntu.com/questions/776435/i-cant-get-1920x1080-with-intel-linux-graphic-driver/776502#776502)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a custom resolution using xrandr. For example to get a display size of 2940 x 1260 at 55 Hz (nice easy-read resolution for an ultra wide screen):

1. sudo cvt 2940 1260 55
2. sudo xrandr --newmode "2944x1260_55.00"  284.00  2944 3144 3456 3968  1260 1263 1273 1303 -hsync +vsync
3. sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 2944x1260_55.00

Note: *Step 2 uses the output of step one. This resolution will now be listed as part of your display options.*

Now if this worked, you may find that your settings are gone after you restart. So to make xrander load the mode after restart:

1. nano $HOME/.xprofile
2. Add the commands from step 2 and 3 to the file.
3. chmod +x $HOME/.xprofile

Your mileage may vary, but his worked like a charm for me. Hopefully it gets you down the right track at least.