# Resolution messed up after removing nvidia-driver-390

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics, display-resolution

I installed nvidia-driver-390, it had higher frame rates than the integrated intel GPU, but it felt worse (about 30) for whatever reason. So I uninstalled it and rebooted the system. The resolution now is 960x540, but my screen is 1366×768 and there is no option to change it to 1366×768 in LXRandR.

How can I set the resolution back to 1366x768

Answer (score 1):

i have this problem and found answer from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323225):

create one `Intel_more_resolution.sh` by this containers:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1600x900_60.00"
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --off --output DP-1 --off --output eDP-1 --primary  --mode 1600x900_60.00 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-2 --off
```

and run `sudo chmod 755 Intel_more_resolution.sh & sudo ./Intel_more_resolution.sh` and you could see change in resolution.

but it must be done for every time you restart your Linux for better instruction see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776435/i-cant-get-1920x1080-with-intel-linux-graphic-driver).

[image]
have a happy day and night.